# Parse bit strings in Perl

Tags: perl, binary

When working with unpack, I had hoped that b3 would return a bitstring, 3 bits in length.

The code that I had hoped to be writing (for parsing a websocket data packet) was:

```
my($FIN,$RSV1, $RSV2, $RSV3, $opcode, $MASK, $payload_length) = unpack('b1b1b1b1b4b1b7',substr($read_buffer,0,2));
```

I noticed that this doesn't do what I had hoped.

If I used b16 instead of the template above, I get the entire 2 bytes loaded into first variable as "1000000101100001".

That's great, and I have no problem with that.

I can use what I've got so far, by doing a bunch of substrings, but is there a better way of doing this? I was hoping there would be a way to process that bit string with a template similar to the one I attempted to make. Some sort of function where I can pass the specification for the packet on the right hand side, and a list of variables on the left?

Edit: I don't want to do this with a regex, since it will be in a very tight loop that will occur a lot.

Edit2: Ideally it would be nice to be able to specify what the bit string should be evaluated as (Boolean, integer, etc).

Comment: @SinanÜnür $read_buffer is the binary data for the packet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, your goal is to split the 2-bytes input to 7 new variables.
For this purpose you can use bitwise operations. This is an example of how to get your `$opcode` value:

```
my $b4 = $read_buffer & 0x0f00;  # your mask to filter 9-12 bits
$opcode = $b4 >> 8;              # rshift your bits
```

You can do the same manipulations (maybe in a single statement, if you want) for all your variables and it should execute at a resonable good speed.

Comment: I usually shift first (e.g. `my $opcode = ( $read_buffer >> 8 ) & 0xF;`) because it's usually clearer as to how many bits are bits are being extracted.